# Proving $x^{1/1} = x$

Tags: real-analysis, roots, exponentiation

I am reading the book "Analysis I" from Terence Tao, and I have a doubt about an argument that I am using in my proof.

In first place, we already know this:

"**Lemma 5.6.6 (a).** If $x, y \geq 0$ are real numbers and $n \geq 1$ is a positive integer. Then $y^{n} = x$, if $y = x^{1/n}$."

The proposition I "proved" is the following:

**Proposition.** For each real number $x \geq 0$, $x^{1/1} = x$.

*Proof.* Let $x \geq 0$, a real number. Let $a := x^{1/1}$, and from Lemma 5.6.6 (a), we have $a^{1} = x$. We know $a^{1} = a$, and hence $a = x$. We can conclude $x^{1/1} = x$.

My question is basically if the argument in my proof when I define $a := x^{1/1}$, allows me to apply the Lemma 5.6.6 (a), and establish $a^{1} = x$. Is this correct?

Comment: $1/1$ is just $1$. We already know $x^1=x$, and in fact it is most certainly used somewhere leading up to the proof of Lemma $5.6.6(a)$. So trying to use the lemma to prove it is probably circular.

Comment: Are that lemma and proposition from Terry Tao's book? If not, what is the problem from his book you are referring to? Maybe you want to prove $x^0=1$ for $x\neq 0$?